# How to use regex for my List<String> in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

```
class Article{
 final String id;
 final List<ArticleArray> arrays;
}

class ArticleArray {
  final String id;
  final String array;
}

TextFormField(
onChanged: (_searchinput) {
   List<String> searcharray  = _searchinput.split(',');
),

  _articlesForDisplay = _articles.where((article){
        for(int i = 0; i < article.arrays.length; i++)
       {
        searchinit = article.arrays[i].arrays.toLowerCase();
        }
        return searchinit.contains(
          RegExp(//necessary code here, caseSensitive: false),
         );})
```

basically what i am trying to do is i am trying to search
array by array like:
-Textformfields follows the user input and every time "," is entered,i
put that word into "searcharray".
-Then i initiate a search in my function(total code is not needed to write here,
i included necessary functions),i try to use "regexp" function to search for the arrays
in my article archives.

Example:

```
articles[0].arrays[0].array = 'a1'
articles[0].arrays[1].array = 'a2'

articles[1].arrays[0].array = 'a1'
articles[1].arrays[1].array = 'b2'

searcharray = ['a1','b2']
```

Here,basically what i try to do is i try to search my article arrays by every list of arrays as possible so it matches the right one. Thats what i want.

Comment: rather use search suggestion

Comment: @JanviPatel link/source please.

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/implementing-auto-complete-search-list-a8dd192bd5f6

Comment: i posted same in answer plz upvote the answer

Comment: can't see it  ??

Comment: wait i will repost

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your specific requirements.

Here, I define a RegExp that I try to match to at least one item of my data.

```
void main() {
  List<String> data = ['a1','b2', 'c3', 'a4', 'a5', 'd6'];
  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"(a\d+)");
  print(data.any((item) => exp.hasMatch(item)));
}
```

Comment: I think this can help me.But i just want you to explain what this does:
`RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"(a\d+)");`  
So i can use it clearly.

Comment: This defines the Regular expression as looking for a string containing 'a' followed by 1 or several digits. If you tell me what you are searching for, I could fine-tune this solution. Or, you may have a look at RegExp patterns here: https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-regexp-regular-expression-objects

Comment: Please check the update.I explained what i want in details,ask me if you want to know more so i can help to clear it up.